# IOS MapKit pin doesn't at the current location

Tags: ios, location, mapkit

I want to use the map view show my current location, my test device is Ipad mini(WIFI, IOS7).

I update current location to my UIMapView in the delegate method

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

{

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
MyAnnotation *start = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
start.coordinate = currentLocation.coordinate;

[_mapView addAnnotation:start];

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation.coordinate, 100, 100);

[_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

}

But I get the result like the below photo, my current location is at the blue point, but the red pin is at another place. I think the pin should match my current location, the blue point. But it didn't. Can somebody tell me the reason, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try adding your annotation in the map view's delegate method didUpdateUserLocation and using userLocation.coordinate instead of your own CLLocationManager (which may be using different filter criteria than the map view's internal location mgr for the blue dot).

Comment: My didUpateUserLocation delegate method is like the below code, but it get same result.:- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion reg =
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 100, 100);
    mapView.region = reg;
}

Comment: The code in your comment doesn't add an annotation.  It just sets the map's region.  I'm suggesting to do the addAnnotation (as well as setting the region) in didUpdateUserLocation instead of didUpdateLocations.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that GPS isn't 100% accurate and especially not inside buildings